# How do new columns in polars get their types when using .when.then?

Tags: python, python-polars

New to polars, using the latest 0.18.2

I want to add a new column to a dataframe, using `pl.when.then.otherwise`, but I'm confused when the new column "inherits" the type of an existing one, and when it doesn't.

An example dataframe:

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"a": ["x", "y"], "b": [1, 2]}, schema={"a": pl.Utf8, "b": pl.UInt8})
df
Out:
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ u8  │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ x   ┆ 1   │
│ y   ┆ 2   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Here the new column gets the same type (and name) as column `b`:

```
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("a") == "x")
    .then(pl.col("b"))
    .otherwise(5)
)
Out:
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ u8  │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ x   ┆ 1   │
│ y   ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

If I add one more `when.then`, the new column gets a different type:

```
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("a") == "x")
    .then(pl.col("b"))
    .when(pl.col("a") == "y")
    .then(0)
    .otherwise(5)
)
Out:
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i32 │ # <-- Int32 instead of UInt8
╞═════╪═════╡
│ x   ┆ 1   │
│ y   ┆ 0   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

But with another small change the type is back to `UInt8`, even though the changed condition doesn't even match any rows:

```
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("a") == "x")
    .then(pl.col("b"))
    .when(pl.col("a") == "y")
    .then(0)
    .otherwise(pl.col("b")) # <-- changed to pl.col('b') instead of a number
)
Out:
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ u8  │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ x   ┆ 1   │
│ y   ┆ 0   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Sometimes an integer value without an explicit casting to `pl.UInt8` changes the type of the whole column, and sometimes it doesn't. Why? And how do I ensure that the new column gets the same type as before? Do I have to explicitly cast every time?

Comment: I'm not sure why that particular cast happens in your example, but polars determines the [supertype](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars_core/utils/fn.get_supertype.html), for example you could have: `when().then(1).when().then("foo")` in which case "str" would be the supertype.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense, however, all the values in the example are compatible with both UInt8 and Int32, and the same set of values gets cast to a different type, which is what confuses me.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if the type is being "incorrectly inferred" or not in this particular example. Hopefully someone with more knowledge on the subject can inform us.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note is that native python doesn't distinguish between the bit size of Ints and Floats nor does it differentiate signed and unsigned ints so when you're feeding your expression literal 0s and 5s it's just receiving int. To avoid excessive parsing, if you give it an int that is smaller than an i64 then it just assumes it should be i32. There is an expression you can use to tell it to find the smallest bit size `shrink_dtype`. Even that function won't take your int and make them unsigned.

The other thing to notice is that you get different behavior with your last test if you were to assign it to a new column:

```
df.with_columns(c=
    pl.when(pl.col("a") == "x")
    .then(pl.col("b"))
    .when(pl.col("a") == "y")
    .then(0)
    .otherwise(pl.col("b")) # <-- changed to pl.col('b') instead of a number
)
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ u8  ┆ i32 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ x   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ y   ┆ 2   ┆ 0   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

So in this case, with the same expression, but this time assigned to a new column, you get the default i32. There is seemingly some deference to the original dtype of the column whereby the parser will decide that an ambiguous 0 can be made into a u8, as in your test.

I think that the issue is in the order of resolving the when/then statements but I'm not sure so I'll just close with workarounds.

**Work arounds**

Small scale:

Make your own `pl.lit` function with a default dtype to your liking with a short name.  For instance

```
def u(x):
    return pl.lit(x, pl.UInt8())
```

then you can just wrap literal unsigned 8-bit integers in `u()` like this:

```
df.with_columns(c=
    pl.when(pl.col("a") == "x")
    .then(pl.col("b"))
    .when(pl.col("a") == "y")
    .then(u(0))
    .otherwise(u(5))
)
```

You could make a similar function for every dtype if you wanted to.

Generally it's bad practice to give a function such a short name for anything somebody else will look at but if you're just doing it for convenience in a live session then it won't hurt anyone.

Bigger scale:

Make your own `with_columns` replacement which aims to cast the result back to the original when it's a replacement and then monkey patch it to the `pl.DataFrame` namespace:

```
def cols(self, *kwarg, **kwargs):
    """a replacement for with_columns that attempts to cast results to original dtypes"""
    all_exprs=[]
    check_cols=[]
    for kw in kwarg:
        if kw.meta.output_name() in self.columns:
            all_exprs.append(kw.alias(f"{kw.meta.output_name()}____backup"))
            all_exprs.append(kw.cast(self.schema[kw.meta.output_name()], strict=False))
            check_cols.append(kw.meta.output_name())
        else:
            all_exprs.append(kw)            
    for key,value in kwargs.items():
        if key in self.columns:
            all_exprs.append(value.alias(f"{key}____backup"))
            all_exprs.append(value.cast(self.schema[key], strict=False))
            check_cols.append(key)
        else:
            all_exprs.append(value.alias(key))
    df=self.with_columns(all_exprs)
    revert_backup=[]
    good_to_drop=[]
    for col in check_cols:
        if df.filter(pl.col(col).is_null()!=pl.col(f"{col}____backup").is_null()).height == 0:
            good_to_drop.append(f"{col}____backup")
        else:
            revert_backup.append(col)
            good_to_drop.append(col)
    return df.drop(good_to_drop).rename({f"{x}____backup":x for x in revert_backup})
pl.DataFrame.cols=cols
del cols
```

The way this works is to check all of the expressions to see if their output name matches any existing columns. If it does then it'll do that expression twice, once as-is and again with an explicit nonstrict cast back to its parent dtype. It then checks the backup against the casted version to see if their `null`ness is always the same. If it is then it means the cast is lossless and it drops the backup. If that check fails then it drops the casted version and renames the backup to the original name. If you have expensive expressions then doing them twice will be suboptimal. We could do the casting in a separate step but then if you only have cheap expressions, adding serial steps would be suboptimal. I suspect the inefficiency of this is why this behavior isn't already the default.

Nonetheless, this allows you to do:

```
df.cols(pl.when(pl.col("a") == "x")
    .then(pl.col("b"))
    .when(pl.col("a") == "y")
    .then(1)
    .otherwise(5))

shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ u8  │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ x   ┆ 1   │
│ y   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

but if you put in a -1, for instance:

```
df.cols(pl.when(pl.col("a") == "x")
    .then(pl.col("b"))
    .when(pl.col("a") == "y")
    .then(-1)
    .otherwise(5))

shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i32 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ x   ┆ 1   │
│ y   ┆ -1  │
└─────┴─────┘
```

it'll revert to the default dtype.